# SharePoint peoplePicker. Отображать другое поле из AD

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint

Как можно отобразить другое поле из Active Directory в поле типа "Пользователь"?

Например:

```
extensionAttiribute1
```

Comment: А разве расширенные атрибуты из AD хранятся в SP-профиле пользователя? Насколько я поняла, они есть в профиле Office 365, а вот то, что их можно достать из SP-профиля, не слышала...

Comment: Да, в SharePoint Profile Service можно создать дополнительное поле и заполнять его из поля в Active Directory.

Comment: В стандартном контроле выбора пользователей расширенных полей не увидела, наверно придется писать собственный тип...

Comment: Нет, тип свой писать не нужно, посмотрите мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно сделать.
Поле "Пользователь" отображает данные из списка информации о пользователях.
Мы можем самостоятельно добавить поля в этот список. Потом своим пользовательским кодом брать данные из Active Directory и переносить в созданное нами поле. 
Но если у нас версия SharePoint не Foundation, то у нас есть Служба-приложение профилей. В нем мы можем создать новое поле для описания пользователя, соотнести его с полем из Active Directory, пометить поле как "Реплицируемое" и начать полную синхронизацию. После ее окончания в списке информации о пользователях мы сможем увидеть созданное нами новое поле и ссылать на отображение данных именно из него в поле "Пользователь".

Comment: Если честно, ничего не поняла из Вашего ответа. Я так понимаю, изначально вопрос был про SP Online. Зашла в Центр Администрирования SP (Office 365). Там есть страница "Управление свойствами пользователей", да свойство добавить можно, но сопоставления с полями AD (или хотя бы полями из профиля Office 365) не нашла. Можете скрин приложить.

Comment: Нет, речь идёт о SharePoint on-premises. Как соединить поля из user profile service c атрибутами из active directory написано [здесь](https://sharepointclick.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/mapping-custom-active-directory-fields-to-sharepoint/). В SharePoint Online были ограничения на синхронизацию с нестандартными полями. Точнее на создание новых привязок.

Comment: Ясно. Просто Вы поставили в вопросе тег "sharepoint-online", вот я подумала... ввели в заблуждение, т.к. в вопросе версия SP не описана ;)

Comment: Тэг убрал, спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, если Вы удовлетворены собственным ответом, то пометьте его "как ответ на вопрос", а то он будет висеть в списках как вопрос без ответа. Это неудобно для тех, кто ищет вопросы, на которые нет ответов.

Comment: Пометил. Спасибо! Я еще в англ. версии задавал вопрос, там сразу ответил: [ссылка](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157420/sharepoint-people-picker-show-other-ad-attribute)

Comment: ок. На англ.стеке хорошо, если бы не мой ужасный английский. Его не хватает, чтобы отвечать на вопросы. Сижу там как читатель :) Хорошо, что здесь (на русск. стеке) начало больше появляться русскоязычных разработчиков по SharePoint.

Comment: [Здесь](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) пытались создать русскоязычное сообщество по SharePoint, но не набрали голосов...